# Firefox does not render expected way in flexbox with 'max-width: max-content'

Tags: html, css, firefox, flexbox

Firefox does not include padding when below code

https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-atagwz?embed=1&file=index.html

please check the live in stackblitz

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <a> asdf </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a> asdf </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a> asdf </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a> asdf </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
  list-style-position: outside;
  display: flex;
}

li {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

a {
  display: flex;
  padding: 0 12px;
  text-decoration: none;
  max-width: max-content;
}
```

### firefox

[image]

### chrome (expected way)

[image: https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-atagwz?embed=1&file=index.html]

Why firefox render this way?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's the `max-width` or `max-content` that is causing the problem. I think it's the nested flex container structure. (I've seen different browsers handle nested flex properties differently.)

Consider a simpler structure—which works across all major browsers and is also HTML5 semantically solid:

```css
nav {
  display: flex;
}

a {
  display: flex;
  padding: 0 12px;
  text-decoration: none;
  max-width: max-content;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <a> asdf </a>
  <a> asdf </a>
  <a> asdf </a>
  <a> asdf </a>
</nav>
```